# SVG Not Rendering Correctly in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

I am developing a SVG logo for a project, and, when testing it, the logo renders fine in Google Chrome, but doesn't render properly in Firefox.

The logo in Google Chrome, as it should look is:
[image: Logo in Google Chrome]

And the logo in Firefox is:
[image: Logo in Firefox]

The code I have used for the SVG is:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="svg-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect id="svg-logo-rectangle" x="3.744" y="47.804" />
    <text id="svg-logo-text-crocker" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 130 98.3037)">Crocker</text>
    <text id="svg-logo-text-estates" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 130 163.3037)" font-size="64.9214">Estates</text>
    <text id="svg-logo-text-c" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 118.3037)">C</text>
    <text id="svg-logo-text-e" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 55 168.3037)">E</text>
    <text id="svg-logo-text-house-finder" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 131 197.3037)">House Finder</text>
    <g id="svg-logo-house-1">
        <rect x="5.181" y="15.696" width="26.502" height="26.502"/>
        <polygon points="5.181,15.696 18.393,2.696 31.604,15.696    "/>
        <rect class="window" x="7.559" y="18.737" />
        <rect class="window" x="21.684" y="18.737" />
        <rect class="window" x="21.684" y="31.862" />
        <rect class="door" x="8.871" y="36.011" width="4.875" height="6.703"/>
    </g>
    <g id="svg-logo-house-2">
        <rect x="46.493" y="15.696" width="26.502" height="26.502"/>
        <polygon points="46.493,15.696 59.705,2.696 72.916,15.696   "/>
        <rect class="window" x="48.871" y="18.737" />
        <rect class="window" x="62.996" y="18.737" />
        <rect class="window" x="62.996" y="31.862" />
        <rect class="door" x="50.184" y="36.011" width="4.875" height="6.703"/>
    </g>
    <g id="svg-logo-house-3">
        <rect x="87.806" y="15.696" width="26.502" height="26.502"/>
        <polygon points="87.806,15.696 101.018,2.696 114.229,15.696     "/>
        <rect class="window" class="window" x="90.184" y="18.737" width="7.5" height="7.5"/>
        <rect class="window" class="window" x="104.309" y="18.737" width="7.5" height="7.5"/>
        <rect class="window" class="window" x="104.309" y="31.862" width="7.5" height="7.5"/>
        <rect class="door" x="91.496" y="36.011" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Do you have any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: `<rect id="svg-logo-rectangle" x="3.744" y="47.804" />` is missing dimensions?

Comment: House 3 rectangles have the class defined twice. Perhaps that is a cause?

Comment: House 3s door is also missing dimensions

Comment: The dimensions are defined within the CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only Chrome supports setting rect height and width via CSS currently as that's a new feature of SVG 2. You need to include width and height as attributes in all cases.

Having the same attribute name twice is invalid so you should remove the redundant class attributes too.

Comment: You got it right, spelled it out better and quicker than I could.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing dimensions in multiple locations.

Svg logo rectangle
House 1, all 3 windows
House 2, all 3 windows
House 3, the door